# high dimensional propensity score

Tags: propensity-scores

I have used high dimensional propensity scores in a research paper. I am asked by a reviewer: "If the computation of this score involves estimates that may be biased in any way, discuss this putative bias".

What do you think? I am not sure to understand correctly what is really expected here.

Thank you
Best